# $\text{E}[xW^2 + yW + z] = x \text{E}[W^2] + y \text{E}[W] + z$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am currently helping a friend with a math problem, but I am currently stuck with it. The question asked to prove the following identity, where $x$, $y$, $z$  are constants:

$$\text{E}[xW^2 + yW + z] = x \text{E}[W^2] + y \text{E}[W] + z$$

May I ask, what is the topic that this falls under? I took an interest in statistics, but I'm not sure what topic in statistics this falls under.

Comment: This is probability, not statistics. Are you given any other information? Also, please show your work in attempting to solve this.

Comment: $E[W]$ is linear. See "Linearity of expectation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value If you're looking for proof, use that it is defined by a series, or an integral (depending on your specific context).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $W$ is a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P}),$ then the expected value of $W$ is defined as $\mathbb{E}[W] := \int_\Omega W d \mathbb{P}$ (a Lebesgue integral). Since this integral is linear, it immediately follows that $\mathbb{E}[x W^2 + y W + z] = x \mathbb{E}[W^2] + y \mathbb{E}[W] + z$ (maybe the only thing that you could elaborate on is the fact that $\mathbb{E}[1] = 1,$ but this is trivial as well, because $\int_\Omega 1 \,\,d\mathbb{P} = 1 \cdot \mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1,$ since $\mathbb{P}$ is probabilistic). Hope this clears the air.